# plink request to variable powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, unix, plink

I have the following code:

```
& $Plinkpath -P "22" -v "User@Server" -pw $passw $commands3 | Out-File $Report -Append -Encoding utf8
```

This outputs a file with the information needed but I want to store the plink sentence result into a variable.

I tried:

```
& $Plinkpath -P "22" -v "User@Server" -pw $passw $commands > $Example
$Example = $Plinkpath -P "22" -v "User@Server" -pw $passw $commands
```

And nothing works :(

How can I get the command output into a variable?

Comment: `$Example = plink username@hostname command` actually works. Plink is just a console application, there's nothing Plink-specific  in your question.

Comment: I tried `$Example = plink username@hostname command` and does not work

Comment: `& $Plinkpath -P 22 -v "$usr@$Server" -pw $passw $Param[0] = $Param[1]`
This worked for me! Thx for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does `Invoke-Expression` work for you?

```
$example = Invoke-Expression "$Plinkpath -P '22' -v 'User@Server' -pw $passw $commands"
```

This should capture the command output into the `$example` variable.

Below is the cmdlet description:

```
PS > Get-Help invoke-expression

NAME
    Invoke-Expression

SYNOPSIS
    Runs commands or expressions on the local computer.


SYNTAX
    Invoke-Expression [-Command] <String> [<CommonParameters>]


DESCRIPTION
    The Invoke-Expression cmdlet evaluates or runs a specified string as a command and returns the results of the
    expression or command. Without Invoke-Expression , a string submitted at the command line would be returned
    (echoed) unchanged.
```

Comment: As a general rule, Invoke-Expression should be a last resort.

Comment: @EBGreen Not that I don't agree, but it would be useful to provide some information to back that statement up so that myself and other users can understand why it should be a last resort

Comment: Oh, because it opens your code to code injection attacks.